Using python script to answer an input prompt request
I have a number of python scripts that each insert data into my database and I run all of these through a centralised script that calls and runs them. Within each of the insert scripts there is an input() request to get the folder location of the files that need to be inserted. The location of the data files is the same for all of the insert scripts, but changing these scripts is not an option.
Is there a way I can have my centralised script provide an answer to the input prompt, everytime it prompts?

As an alternative, do the insert scripts take an argument to specify the location?

I believe this is what you're looking for: How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?

import subprocess

folder_location = "/path/to/data/files"
insert_scripts = ["insert_script1.py", "insert_script2.py", "insert_script3.py"]

for script in insert_scripts:
    try:
        subprocess.run(
            ["python", script],
            input=folder_location,
            text=True,
            check=True,
        )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while running {script}: {e}")


How does that work? I mean, how does the patch carry over to the subprocess interpreter?

@wjandrea you're right oops... patch only works within the same process... brainfart... I've edited it to not use patch

Amazing, that looks like it has worked! Thank you!

Although not a requirement of the OP I would definitely be multi-threading/processing here to optimise performance
